# How to make chart fill div and not overflay it in pop-up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chart.js

```js
$(function() {
    //----- OPEN
    $('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var limit = 1000;    //increase number of dataPoints by increasing this

var y = 0;
var data = []; var dataSeries = { type: "line" };
var dataPoints = [];
for (var i = -limit/2; i <= limit/2; i++) {

 y += (Math.random() * 10 - 5);
 dateTime = new Date(1960, 08, 15);

 //dateTime.setMilliseconds(dateTime.getMilliseconds() + i);
 //dateTime.setSeconds(dateTime.getSeconds() + i);
 //dateTime.setMinutes(dateTime.getMinutes() + i);
 //dateTime.setHours(dateTime.getHours() + i);
 dateTime.setDate(dateTime.getDate() + i);
 //dateTime.setMonth(dateTime.getMonth() + i);
 //dateTime.setFullYear(dateTime.getFullYear() + i);

 dataPoints.push({         
  x: dateTime,
  y: y
 });
}

dataSeries.dataPoints = dataPoints;
data.push(dataSeries);               

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
 {
  zoomEnabled: true,      
  title:{
   text: "X Axis Labels adapt automatically on Zooming" 
  },
  axisX :{
   labelAngle: -30
  },
  axisY :{
   includeZero: false
  },
  legend: {
   horizontalAlign: "right",
   verticalAlign: "center"        
  },
  data: data,  // random generator below
 });
 chart.render();
        
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);
 
        e.preventDefault();
    });
 
    //----- CLOSE
    $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
 
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
<style>
    #chartContainer{
        width: 1000px;
        height: 350px;
        background-color: red;
        height:100%;
    }
    .btn {
        background-color:blue;
        color:white;
        
    }
/* Outer */
.popup {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
 
/* Inner */
.popup-inner {
    max-width:800px;
    padding:40px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow:0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border-radius:3px;
    background:#fff;
}
 
/* Close Button */
.popup-close {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    padding-top:4px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    transition:ease 0.25s all;
    -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%);
    transform:translate(50%, -50%);
    border-radius:1000px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:100%;
    color:#fff;
}
 
.popup-close:hover {
    -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
    transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
    background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
    text-decoration:none;
}</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>



<body>
    <a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#">Open Popup #1</a>
 
<div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
    <div class="popup-inner">
        <h2>Wow! This is Awesome! (Popup #1)</h2>
        <p>Donec in volutpat nisi. In quam lectus, aliquet rhoncus cursus a, congue et arcu. Vestibulum tincidunt neque id nisi pulvinar aliquam. Nulla luctus luctus ipsum at ultricies. Nullam nec velit dui. Nullam sem eros, pulvinar sed pellentesque ac, feugiat et turpis. Donec gravida ipsum cursus massa malesuada tincidunt. Nullam finibus nunc mauris, quis semper neque ultrices in. Ut ac risus eget eros imperdiet posuere nec eu lectus.</p>
           <div id="chartContainer"></div>
        <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
        <p><a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a></p>
        <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
    </div>
</div>
    

    <div>
        <h2>Wow! This is Awesome! (Popup #1)</h2>
        <p>Donec in volutpat nisi. In quam lectus, aliquet rhoncus cursus a, congue et arcu. Vestibulum tincidunt neque id nisi pulvinar aliquam. Nulla luctus luctus ipsum at ultricies. Nullam nec velit dui. Nullam sem eros, pulvinar sed pellentesque ac, feugiat et turpis. Donec gravida ipsum cursus massa malesuada tincidunt. Nullam finibus nunc mauris, quis semper neque ultrices in. Ut ac risus eget eros imperdiet posuere nec eu lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div data-popup="popup-1">
    <div id="chartContainer1" style="height: 300px; width: 700px;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Hey, well I was trying to create a dynamic pop-up that would contain a chart and as it seems I've managed to do that. The problem I have though is that once you click on the "pop-up" button the pop-up doesn't fully contain the chart.[image] as can be seen from the first image. The second image displays how I would've wished my page to look like.[image]
The funny part is that I get the display as in second image if I zoom in on my pop-up chart. I'm kinda lost so any advice would be tremendous.

Kind regards, Domen

Comment: I'm noticing you have two chart containers, one of which has a width of 700px, the other has a width of 1000px. Which one is displaying in your example image, `chartContainer` or `chartContainer1`?

Comment: chartContainer, so the one with 1000px.

Comment: chartContainer1 is just added because I was testing something, it may be removed if needed